# Is "a += a" an undifined behaviour such as "i = i++"?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior

I have understand that i = i++ is an undefined behaviour in C . But i have a doubt about a += a . Is it an undefined behaviour too ?

Comment: No, because there is no attempt to modify `a` more than once.

Comment: I see you've taken the time to try it, instead of wasting other peoples time!

Comment: @Deanie: What experiment do you envision one would perform to determine whether `a += a` has behavior defined by the C standard or not? What result of that experiment would indicate the behavior **is** defined by the C standard? What result of that experiment would indicate the behavior **is not** defined by the C standard? If, in the experiment, the value of `a` doubles, does that mean the behavior is defined? Is it possible that, if the behavior of the code is not defined, the observed result could be that the value of `a` doubles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `a += a` is not undefined. The behavior of `i = i++` is not defined by the C standard due to this rule in C 2018 6.5 2:

> If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either a different side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined.

That rule applies because both `i++` and `i =` have side effects of updating `i`, and they are not sequenced. (Although the value computation of `i++`, which produces the **value** to be used in the rest of the expression is sequenced before the assignment, its **side effect** of updating `i` is not sequenced relative to the assignment.)

In `a += a`, the value computation of the right operand (`a`) occurs before the assignment (according to 6.5.16 3), and then `a +=` has the side effect of updating `a`. So:

- There is only one side effect, so there are not two unsequenced side effects.
- There is a side effect on `a` and a value computation of `a`, but they are sequenced.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i understand now ;)